# ruby on rails controller doesn't execute model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, controller, execute

**controller.rb**

```
if @object.save
    Post.method_name(@object)
end
```

**post.rb**

```
def self.method_name(object)
    post_id = 1
    p = Post.new
    p.post_id = post_id
    p.save
end
```

When `Post.method_name(@object)` is executed i cant see a new post added into the table even though i cant see any errors either...

Comment: try with `p.save!` to have an exception if save fails; otherwise test the result of `p.save`

Comment: Are there any validations on post?

Comment: @Baldrick tried, but i get the following error `Validation failed: Post type is not included in the list` @Rubyman there are but why would they affect the record save if i fill all fields correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

i was getting the following error

```
Validation failed: Post type is not included in the list
```

when i used `p.save!`

due to `validates :post_type, :presence => true, :inclusion=> { :in => @allowed_post_types }`

so when i added the post type i was using into the array of `@allowed_post_types`

the problem was resolved